# Should the "serial voting reversal" script be expanded to consider distributed attacks?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, serial-voting

I rarely get downvotes on Stack Overflow (main).

But after posting an opinion on meta that some people disagreed with, I got three downvotes on main in quick succession. All the questions/answers were not active for a long time, so they are almost certainly not "organic" votes.

Then I complained in a comment that downvoting on main is unfair just for expressing your opinion on meta. The comment was upvoted, and the downvotes stopped.

Then someone flagged the comment, it was deleted and the downvotes started again.

The usual guidance when dealing with targeted downvoting is to wait for the "serial voting reversed" script to be instantiated, and in theory it should reverse the invalid downvotes. In practice, this only works if the downvotes come from a single user. If each user of a clique downvotes once, then the downvotes are not reversed.

My proposal is to expand the "serial voting reversed" script to also consider distributed attacks. For example, it could invalidate any downvotes that come from a user that has recently opened the OP's profile. Or it could invalidate any downvotes if the thread is not recently active, and at the same time, the referrer of the request is not from a search engine, or from another post on Stack Overflow that directly links to the specific thread.

Or something else that I haven't thought of. But distributed attacks should stop.

Comment: *downvotes all your posts once more for posting on Meta again ...*

Comment: @rene No, that wont work, it will be reversed. You should downvote **one** post, and hope your buddies do the same (maybe link the profile in chat for better results).

Comment: "_it could invalidate any downvotes that come from a user that has recently opened the OPs profile_" opening a persons profile may very well lead you to posts that are worthy of downvotes. Similarly for the rest of your points the same concern stands. As an example, If I find posts that I believe some OP has already asked before I open their profile to find that old question of theirs and sometimes I find that they have asked it more than 2 times...

Comment: I don't think @rene was being serious, user000001, it was in jest.

Comment: You mean my sock-puppets? Okay, hold my beer ....

Comment: This was on June 18th? That wasn't in quick succession and you also received two upvotes on one of the downvoted, old posts. Should they also be invalidated and count as attacks? What about upvotes on main because someone agrees with the user on meta in general - shouldn't they receive the same treatment then?

Comment: @JeanneDark: No, upvotes and downvotes are not symmetrical, e.g. you can't get question-banned for receiving too many upvotes.

Comment: *"For example, it could invalidate any downvotes that come from a user that has recently opened the OPs profile."* this seems like a bad idea. If I see a couple of low quality questions from a user within a few hours, I often check the OP's profile to see if the quality of their other questions, and will often remind them in the comments if they do appear to all be received poorly. Why should be downvote(s) on the 1 or 2 I saw due to tags I follow be reserved because I viewed their profile...?

Comment: So it's fine to upvote a user's posts on main, regardless of their usefulness, just because I agree with an unrelated opinion expressed by them on meta?

Comment: @Larnu: For the same reason that the vote-reversal script does it when you downvote 3 posts. You are targeting the user, not the content.

Comment: *How* am i targetting the user when i have seen them post 2 bad questions in the tag(s) i follow in a single day and downvoted both...? Are you saying if i see a second bad qusetion from a user on the same day I am not allowed to downvote the second one..?

Comment: "Distributed serial voting", unless you are talking about sock-puppet accounts, is just... voting.

Comment: @Larnu: I think my second proposal covers you, if the post is active it wouldn't count as targeted.

Comment: Ahh, so I can view a user's profile, find a question, edit it to improve grammar (making it active) and then downvote it with no repercussions. :)

Comment: Little early for a beer isn't it, @rene ? 

Comment: @Larnu: Feel free to provide a better solution if you agree that targeted downvotes are unwanted

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I agree that it is voting, the premise of the question is that if it is targeted to the user, rather than the content, it should be reversed.

Comment: I, personally, often don't see them as truly "targetted", @user000001 . If someone visits my profile and finds a bad question/answer and downvotes it, so be it. I'm no going to miss that 2 reputation.

Comment: Targeted upvotes are just as unwanted and at least as problematic because they can make bad content look useful and thereby harm the usefulness of SO for its users and visitors.

Comment: @JeanneDark: ok, feel free to expand the proposal in an answer to suggest upvotes to be included too, this question was prompted by targeted downvotes though.

Comment: @Larnu: It's not about the reputation, but about the post score, and the question ban. The point is that if you open any active user's profile you will find *something* worth downvoting. But why did you do it for *this* user instead of someone else, and why did you look for things to downvote, rather than e.g. to upvote?

Comment: Targetted upvotes are "just as bad" as targetted dowmvotes though, @user000001 . If you want to implement something like this, it needs to be agnostic of the type of vote. It's no good stopping people for downvoting bad questions they've had no interaction with, if you're not going to stop people upvoting several answers/questions where they had no interaction. People upvoting trash (such as for new users because it's "welcoming") honestly annoys be more than people who downvote good content, as it makes it harder to take the trash out.

Comment: @Larnu: I am fine with that

Comment: you got almost 30k and a gold batch in bash, that is not near of loosing it, why are you complaining. no system can find such over tome deletion, and it is basically part f SO life

Comment: They most certainly ***are*** organic votes; I checked into this when I saw your repeated protestations. I also *deleted* those protestations, since they occurred in comments on the Meta site, which is an inappropriate place. An appropriate place would be a moderator flag. (For what it's worth, I don't think anyone flagged those comments of yours. I just happened across them myself and deleted them. Multiple times. I wasn't really happy about it...)

Comment: @CodyGray: may I ask how you know they were organic, and not caused by people going through my profile looking for downvote worthy material? Do moderators get to see the browsing history of the downvoters?

Comment: If someone found downvote-worthy material, then there isn't really an objection that can be raised to the downvotes.

Comment: @CodyGray: [As I said earlier, I respectfully disagree](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408519/should-the-serial-voting-reversal-script-be-expanded-to-consider-distributed-a?noredirect=1#comment849952_408519). If the profile viewers were impartial instead of biased, they would most likely land on upvote worthy material. The premise of this question is how to devise a mechanism to deter such targeted voting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

We don't need to automate something that only happens to a few unfortunate souls  that push the red buttons of some meta visitors. I'm pretty sure this doesn't happen daily and doesn't happen to all OPs of off-beat  meta posts.

I think it is highly unlikely that SE is going to come-up with an algorithm that gets the 'distributed-attacks' (nice tag, are you aiming for the [taxonomist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) badge?) detection right. I don't fancy my legit votes to be mistaken for a distributed attack as I see and vote on a lot of posts that are also seen by a lot of my "buddies".

If you believe your content is targeted by a group of users, flag for a moderator. They have the tools to do a preliminary investigation and if there is ground to believe something fishy is going on they escalate a CM so a dev can look into the voting pattern. This guidance is not new by the way, it is in practice for the last 6 to 8 years.

In the mean time I wouldn't be bothered too much over a few downvotes, specially if the downvotes don't make sense. They will be compensated by upvotes in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should just let it go, it probably doesn't matter for most users of stack overflow. What tripped me and got me mad is that someone flagged my comment where I tried to defend myself, and then the downvotes continued, it was like a strike "under the belt".

Comment: @user000001 let me give you one tip I learned over the years. Don't ever get mad / frustrated over stuff thrown at you here on meta or main. It is not worth your blood pressure.

Comment: See above; nobody flagged your comment. A moderator saw it, got annoyed that someone who knows better would be ranting in an inappropriate place about downvotes, and deleted it. Next time, let's try for neither you *nor* the moderator getting mad. I think that'll be better, @user000001

Answer (score 5):

No. The script to reverse serial votes exists not because downvotes are bad, but because targeting users is bad.

Opening a user profile with the intent to downvote or upvote all their posts is an abuse of your voting privileges. You are supposed to vote based on the usefulness of the content and not because of who the author was.

Opening a user profile to see their other posts is not against the rules in any sense. Reading their old posts and evaluating their usefulness isn't against the rules either. It's not nice though, so such activities should be avoided. As long as you focus on the content, the system shouldn't reverse your votes and mods should not interfere.

It's difficult to know the intent of the person who votes. So if there's no obvious pattern then it's better to give them the benefit of the doubt.

If you strongly believe that someone is targeting you to cause you psychological pain while avoiding the automatic system, then you can gather the evidence and raise a mod flag. Moderators will investigate and escalate this to the Stack Exchange employees if your suspicions are correct.

What you are describing is just a meta-effect. It happens when you post on Meta and draw attention to your posts, whether intentionally or not. People will often view your posts to evaluate the information you posted on meta or to gather more information. Make sure to post useful and correct posts on Stack Overflow to avoid getting downvotes and attract upvotes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't buy this. If the votes were honest they would follow the same distribution as the ones that come when nothing has been recently posted on meta. The fact that they are one-directional, in the opposite direction than the mean, demonstrates that these users are searching for something to downvote. If they were honest they would most likely find upvote-worthy material in my profile, as history has shown.

Comment: @user000001 On one old post you received 1 new downvote and 2 new upvotes.

Comment: @user000001 I don't see any serial voting or targeted voting in your reputation history. I don't see any reason for concern. You seem to be getting way more upvotes than downvotes. For example, you got +2 upvotes and 1 downvote on one of your old questions. Aren't you concerned that someone targetted you with the upvotes?

Comment: @JeanneDark: I'm fine with reversing the upvote too.

Comment: If you don't want any of your posts to receive any votes then simply don't post anything or post as community wiki. Problem solved. There's no reason to remove legitimate votes

Comment: "As long as you focus on the content, the system shouldn't reverse your votes and mods should not interfere." Is this a statement how the system does work or just a wish how it could work? If the former, it is not true. Nobody, except the voter, has knowledge about the focus during voting. The pattern will look the same.

Comment: It is how the system *does* work, although mistakes are occasionally made (which can be and are corrected). The pattern doesn't look the same. For obvious reasons, we can't go into any more details about how we analyze patterns, but none of the moderators were born yesterday, and none of them are new to voting or using the site. @TadeuszKopec